# How to open the python debugger in a new window in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have been wanting to open a new window that contains the debugger and have the code that is being debugged in another window. I have attempted to follow [`this guideline`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/19793#issuecomment-344985923), but I can't seem the desired result.

The desired result would be to have the debugger in one window and as I'm stepping through the code have another window show where I am at in the code at the current debugging step. Is this possible in `vscode`?

Here is a picture describing what I'm trying to communicate:
[image: Image1]

~ Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, VSCode does not support this function.

In the first link, the code edit box and side folder of the two windows are synchronized, but the terminal console cannot.

If you want to separate the code from the console and synchronize when debugging, you could try to set `"console": "externalTerminal"`  in the `launch.json` file. It will open the cmd and display debugging information in the cmd.

Comment: Thank you, for the feedback. The tip you gave is useful!